# Old LEGO movies

Tags: history

As I remember, it was about 1990 maybe some years earlier, there were movies, made by LEGO, they were about 3 minutes long, maybe longer.

It was of course not computer-generated videos but normal, animated movies created with bricks and photographs were made every single frame. It was very fluent and smooth (maybe some animation tricks were used), much much better than those what people make now, but the idea was the same as [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HJ7s7bwoLOk).

It was not from minifigures, but each person (character) was made by many bricks.

I only remember a movie of some soccer players, but there were more of them.

I can't find them on YouTube, I only get present computer animated videos or just amateur movies like the one above.

Comment: I'd swear I saw one sometime ago, with some red-and-white character which could "dissolve" in the field or something.

Comment: @Joubarc Can be. I remember there was also something like morphing plane.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yesss!

I've finally found it.

They were called "LEGO Sport Champions".

Here is the link to watch them on YouTube:

https://www.youtube.com/user/LEGOsports/videos

Answer (score 3):

What you're talking about are often referred to as "brickfilms".

Reddit even has a subreddit for them: [/r/brickfilms](http://www.reddit.com/r/brickfilms). (Honestly, I wouldn't even have remembered about them had I not just stumbled upon the subreddit yesterday.)

Searching YouTube for the term "brickfilm" also gives you a number of results, some tutorials and many actual brickfilms.

(I'm pretty sure Lego itself did not make or sanction any brickfilms. Like any medium or sub-medium, 90% of brickfilms are probably not very well-made.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer (I vote up for try and providing interesting link). Unfortunately, that's not I'm asking for. The movies were made by Lego in 1980s. There were absolutely no minifigures -- characters were made from "normal" bricks (they were larger of course).

Comment: Ah... Can't help you there; I wasn't even born then.